# How Calculate Daily Moving Average (20DMA) of every row of close values where multiple rows available in historical data table in single query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, average

Here's the schema of my  table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistoricalStockDetails]
(
    [CompanySymbol] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [nDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Open] [money] NOT NULL,
    [High] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Low] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Close] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [sDate] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DMA200] [float] NULL,
    [DMA100] [float] NULL,
    [DMA20] [float] NULL,
    [DMA50] [float] NULL
)
```

Here is Sample data 30 rows. I want to calculate 20DMA for every row and update it.

Please suggest simple way how can I do this in SQL Server 2008 R2. I try to do this by using a CURSOR but its very time consuming because of lot of data. I have 1800 stocks  and all historical data of that. Now I want to calculate DMA values and update table.

Thanks in advance.

```
Symbol  nDate   Open    High    Low Close   Volume  sDate   DMA20  
A   11/18/99 12:00 AM   45.5    50  40  44  44739900    11/18/1999  NULL
A   11/19/99 12:00 AM   42.94   43  39.8    40.38   10897100    11/19/1999  NULL
A   11/22/99 12:00 AM   41.31   44  40.1    44  4705200 11/22/1999  NULL
A   11/23/99 12:00 AM   42.5    43.63   40  40  4274400 11/23/1999  NULL
A   11/24/99 12:00 AM   40.13   41.94   40  41.06   3464400 11/24/1999  NULL
A   11/26/99 12:00 AM   40.88   41.5    40.8    41.19   1237100 11/26/1999  NULL
A   11/29/99 12:00 AM   41  42.44   40.6    42.13   2914700 11/29/1999  NULL
A   11/30/99 12:00 AM   42  42.94   40.9    42.19   3083000 11/30/1999  NULL
A   12/1/99 12:00 AM    42.19   43.44   41.9    42.94   2115400 12/1/1999   NULL
A   12/2/99 12:00 AM    43.75   45  43.2    44.13   2195900 12/2/1999   NULL
A   12/3/99 12:00 AM    44.94   45.69   44.3    44.5    2175700 12/3/1999   NULL
A   12/6/99 12:00 AM    45.25   46.44   45.2    45.75   1610000 12/6/1999   NULL
A   12/7/99 12:00 AM    45.75   46  44.3    45.25   1585100 12/7/1999   NULL
A   12/8/99 12:00 AM    45.25   45.63   44.8    45.19   1350400 12/8/1999   NULL
A   12/9/99 12:00 AM    45.25   45.94   45.3    45.81   1451400 12/9/1999   NULL
A   12/10/99 12:00 AM   45.69   45.94   44.8    44.75   1190800 12/10/1999  NULL
A   12/13/99 12:00 AM   45.5    46.25   44.4    45.5    2875900 12/13/1999  NULL
A   12/14/99 12:00 AM   45.38   45.38   42.1    43  1665900 12/14/1999  NULL
A   12/15/99 12:00 AM   42  42.31   41  41.69   2087100 12/15/1999  NULL
A   12/16/99 12:00 AM   42  47.25   42  47.25   1848300 12/16/1999  NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what DMA is, but I think you are looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT H1.nDate, AVG(H2.High) AS AverageHighLast20Rows

(SELECT nDate, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY nDate) AS Ranked FROM HistoricalStockDetails) H1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT nDate, High, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY nDate) AS Ranked FROM HistoricalStockDetails) H2
ON H2.Ranked BETWEEN H1.Ranked AND H1.Ranked - 20

GROUP BY H1.nDate
```